# How do I interface to this flexible flat cable connector?

Tags: connector, cables, flexible

I've noticed this connector on a lot of boards, and I was wondering if anyone knew where to source them? I can't seem to find them on digikey.com anywhere. What I'd really like is to get a male connector for this to breadboard the contacts. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's actually a SMD board connector; it just happens to be connected to the end of a flexible cable.

Comment: Well that would certainly explain why I couldn't find them on Digikey - I was looking under the wrong categories. Any idea how one would go about breadboarding such a thing?

Comment: You'd have to solder it to a DIP adapter.

Comment: Making a custom breakout for these is a great intro to toner transfer PCB etching.  If you are tricky and surface mount your pins (consider using single row right angle ones) you can avoid drilling any holes at all.

Answer (score 3):

To compliment Gonziks answer, another brand that is very similar is the Panasonic F4S series:

[Example](http://uk.farnell.com/panasonic-ew/axt530224/board-board-connector-receptacle/dp/1924255)

[image: Example Picture]

Answer (score 1):

These look like Molex SlimStack 0.4mm or 0.5mm board to board interconnects (http://www.molex.com/molex/products/group?channel=products&key=slimstack). Breakout boards for these are not common. You'll have to either do a board spin or flywire 40 gauge magnet wire to interface with these.